# Got two plots when using quiver to draw arrows in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I'm new to Julia. I was trying to draw arrows starting from [X[i], Y[i]], and points to the direction of [VX[i], VY[i]]. However, I'm getting the arrows I wanted, but also other few lines which seem to be the mirror of the arrows. Why is this happening?

Here's the code snippet and the result I get.
I guess it has something to do with the y-axis. But I don't understand very well about the mechanism of `quiver` in Julia. Could someone explain a little bit about it and show me what is the right way to remove those straight lines?
Thank you!

```
Using Plots
X = [2, 10, 12, 20, 22, 30]
Y = [2, 10, 12, 20, 22, 30]
VX = [2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8]
VY = [2, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8]
white_img = fill(Gray(1.0), 50, 50)
plot(white_img)
quiver!(X,Y,quiver=(VX,VY))
```

[Plot result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00HeW.png)

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with `quiver` but the interaction with `plot(white_img)`, as `quiver(X, Y, quiver = (VX, VY))` works as expected. Could you explain the relevance of the white image?

Comment: It seems that plotting the image for some reason inverts the y-axis, which then means subsequent `plot!` calls will inherit that inverted axis.

Comment: The original application was to draw the ball trajectory and its velocity on a background image (the court), where I had the same situation. In the description above, I'm showing a simplified version of the original code, and replacing the background image with a white image. @NilsGudat

Comment: I understand that the axis is inverted, but why would there be a mirrored copy of the arrows? It makes no sense to me... @NilsGudat

Comment: This is probably just a bug caused by an unexpected interplay between `quiver` and the inverted axis.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a known bug: [1](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1498) [2](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/3366) [3](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/4709) with the default GR backend. If `yflip = false` isn't an option (i.e. you do want the axis to be flipped), then try the PyPlot backend (i.e. add the PyPlot package and set `backend(:pyplot)` before calling the plot functions). The issues mention that this works fine when using the PyPlot backend.

Comment: Didn't expect it to be such an old bug... Thanks! @SundarR

Comment: Indeed, thanks! @NilsGudat